# How to use functions next, nextAll, find on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically create `select` elements and try to hide new elements after the current, but the `nextAll()` function doesn't see the new elements.

```
    <div id="templates-block">    
    <div>
        <select class="select-template" id="select-template-0"></select>
        <!-- ADDED ELEMENTS  
        <select class="select-template" id="select-template-665"></select>
        <select class="select-template" id="select-template-666"></select> -->
    </div>
    </div>

$('#templates-block').on('change', '.select-template', function () {
  $(this).nextAll().hide();
});
```

Comment: To answer this we need to see the related HTML. `nextAll()` itself is unrelated to any dynamic element concerns; so long as it's in the DOM when the function is called the target will be selected. My assumption is that the content you're trying to target is not a sibling of `this`

Comment: Thx, i understood what the problem was